# Stop music from playing in headless browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I was learning how to play music using selenium so I wrote a program which would be used as a module to play music. Unfortunately I exited the python shell without exiting the headless browser and now the song is continuously playing.
Could someone tell me how I can find the current headless browser and exit it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include in your script to stop the music before closing the session of your headless browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Linux box, You can easily find the process Id with `ps aux| grep chrome` command and Kill it. If you are on Windows kill the process via Task Manager